# How to install grub on this system

Tags: 13.10, windows, uefi, grub-efi

I have two Hard disk drives, as shown in the screenshot

[image: 1TB HDD]
[image: 500GB HDD]

First HDD (Sda) is a **MBR Disk** and second HDD (Sdb) is a **GPT Disk** (Which has windows 8.1x64). I have installed ubuntu on *Sda4* disk and windows 8.1 on *Sdb4*. I need to setup grub to boot both windows and ubuntu OSes with **EFI** capable mode (my motherboard is intel DH77KC and it has **UEFI bios**)

I tried to install grub and search for Windows 8 but it doesn't detect win8, also the windows 8 disk is inaccessible on ubuntu... I have to disable *EFI mode* so I can boot grub before it automatically boots up windows 8...but without efi mode, win 8 doesn't boot, so I need to install grub on efi support without re-installing ubuntu. is it possible? only windows 8 is on efi mode, windows 7 is mbr mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really don't want to reinstall Ubuntu, you can try to convert your install into UEFI mode [this way](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI#Converting_Ubuntu_into_EFI_mode). But it may fail as your Ubuntu disk is not GPT.

If it fails, then backup your documents onto an external disk, format your sda disk in GPT, [set up your BIOS (UEFI firmware) in UEFI mode](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI#Set_up_the_BIOS_in_EFI_or_Legacy_mode), and reinstall Ubuntu on sda.

Comment: Thanks for answering,I have a question. If I mange to reinstall ubuntu in EFI mode, grub will recognize my EFI-capable windows 8, but will grub recognize my non-efi capable Windows 7 ?

Comment: It will, but the GRUB menu will not allow you to boot Win7 (the Win7 entry in GRUB will fail). GRUB cannot manage a mix of UEFI and non-UEFI systems.

Comment: You can convert a BIOS-mode Windows to boot in EFI mode as described [here.](https://gitorious.org/tianocore_uefi_duet_builds/pages/Windows_x64_BIOS_to_UEFI) Alternatively, [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) can switch boot modes seamlessly; however, it can fail in the case of complex setups and on some computers. In order to work, you must edit `refind.conf`: Uncomment the `scanfor` line and ensure that `hdbios` is among the options.

Comment: @RodSmith it is helpfull! thank you for commenting :D